# Create "tag" from text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create kind of *tag* for each item in a loop. The idea is to click on each item separately and them allow to make a AJAX request but certainly I have not idea to achieve this. I am using Bootstrap as CSS framework so maybe that's help a bit. The pics below belongs to a Bootstrap alert element:

[image]

But is pretty much what I want to achieve. Let's take this simple PHP loop as example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    echo '<span class="label">Item '. $i .'</span>';
}
```

How do I wrap each ItemN in a simple element and add a X icon or symbol so I can click on it and make a AJAX request for delete that item? Can any give me some help?

Comment: _"wrap each ItemN in a simple element and add a X icon or symbol"_, why dont you just do that then? `<div><span>Item $i</span><span class="close">x</span></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Php, but I will answer it just with HTML

from bs docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts), this is the markup you need to build that "alert"

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
   <button type="button" class="close ajax-close" data-id="5"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

Notice I added `ajax-close` class to close button, so you can trigger the ajax call when it is clicked, then you just need a script:

```
$('.ajax-close').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/test/" + $(this).data("id"),
        context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
       //....
    });
});
```

Notice I included a data-id attribute and passed to the url so you can know which element delete form your data base, this of course can change according to your needs.

Hope it helps